# How to Pass List as parameter in REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api

I have a requirement where we will receive a parent product id and List of childProductInfo from other system.

Our task in `SFDC` will be to find the existing parent product (`1st input parameter : string parentProdId`) and search for existing child product (`2nd input parameter : List<childProductInfo>`).

If we will find all incoming child parameters are there in SFDC then its ok , if there are indeed some new feed is coming, then `insert` new products with the parameters given as input.

I have implemented this requirement as `SOAP web service`.

But, I want to implement this as `REST API`.

I know we have to write a global static post method (`@HttpPost`), but can we pass a `List` as a `parameter` ?

Comment: Did you try that and receive any error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Providing `childProductInfo` can be serialized (which is can if it is a simple Apex class) an `@HttpPost` can handle a `List`:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/xxx/*') 
global class Temp {

    global class ChildProductInfo {
        public String info;
        public Integer moreInfo;
        // ...
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost(Id parentProdId, List<ChildProductInfo> childProdInfos) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In my experience with `@RestResource` any signature problems are reported at compile time.

The JSON to be posted to the above would look like this:

```
{
    "parentProdId": "...",
    "childProdInfos": [{"info": "abc", "moreInfo": 123}, {"info": "xyz", "moreInfo": 789}]
}
```

Comment: Thank you!. With the help of above data and with the workbench REST tool. I could able to understand the flow.